# worst case runtime

Tags: runtime, big-o

Can someone help me find the worst case runtime of the following in big o notation please?

```
    public void five(int[] A, int[] B) {
        int n=A.length;
        int m=B.length;
        for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<=i; j++) {
                B[i]=j;
            } 
        }
        for (int p=n-1; p>=0; p--) {
            for (int q=p-1; q>=0; q--) {
                A[p]=q; 
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: That's weird code, since it's specifically looping when it doesn't have any reason to. Generally, Big-O questions go on [CS.SE].

Answer (score 0):

The loops have Big O of m Squared and n squared respectively and hence the worst case time complexity of the entire code is Big O of N squared if N>M or Big O of M squared if M>N.

Having said that, the actual functionality of the code seems very weird and has unnecessary redundancy. There is no clear reason for a nested loop as pointed out in comments.